# Citrus framework "no matching constant for [520]" - Custom HTTP Status Codes

Tags: java, http-status-codes, citrus-framework, spring-framework-beans

i've got a problem when I try to run my Citrus v.2.7.5 Tests with an API on a server which responds customized HTTP-Status-Codes to my citrus client. My tests are throwing IllegalArgument Exceptions because the Server responds an message with an 520 Http-Status-Code.

I think the problem is because of the spring-web v.4.3.14 framework which is used by Citrus. The spring-web contains an HttpStatus class with enums of valid Status-Codes. When u try to make a valueOf() of a custom status-code which is not "valid" it will throw an error:

```
/**
 * Return the enum constant of this type with the specified numeric value.
 * @param statusCode the numeric value of the enum to be returned
 * @return the enum constant with the specified numeric value
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if this enum has no constant for the specified numeric value
 */
public static HttpStatus valueOf(int statusCode) {
    HttpStatus status = resolve(statusCode);
    if (status == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No matching constant for [" + statusCode + "]");
    }
    return status;
```

}

In newer versions (5.x) of spring-web this error is fixxed and u can use custom http-status-codes but citrus works with this older version....
Maybe i'm wrong and the exception get's thrown somewhere else, but it has to do with the custom http-status-code, because if we get an 200 HTTP-Status-code everything works fine.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem with citrus?

Comment: Citrus 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT uses Spring 5.0. The release for 2.8.0 is planned for Q4 2018. Snapshots are available via labs.consol.de Maven repository

Comment: Good to know. Thank you very much! :)